# display two line of shadow if text is one line also

Tags: html, css

we are displaying text on image & we are giving shadow for that text [here](http://sb.kidsdial.com/fanbook).

if text is two lines, than it will display shadow for two lines.

[image]

if text is one line, than it will display shadow for one line

[image]

what we need is we want to **display two line of shadow if text is one line also**.

```
.fanbook-name {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); /* add this */
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.fanbook-name b {
    /* bottom: 25px; */
    color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
    /* position: relative; */
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.fanbook-image li {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 1%; /* change this */
    margin-left: 0.5%;
    margin-right: 0.5%;
    position: relative; /* add this */
    width: 24%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a `min-height` with the value of the `line-height * 2` calculation. Easy.